# Lint on C code: parameter of function (a pointer) could be const. *But* I am writing to passed pointer

Tags: c, lint

I'm using Lint for the first time and it's telling me the following:

```
parameter 'p_h_attr' of function
    'get_dev_info_service_id_attr(ble_attribute_t *)' could be const
```

For this function:

```
static void get_dev_info_service_id_attr(ble_attribute_t *p_h_attr)
{
    p_h_attr->p_attr = (void *)ble_char_system_id_value;
    p_h_attr->attr_len = sizeof(ble_char_system_id_value);
}
```

However, of course, the compiler complains if I make p_h_attr a const because I'm writing into the passed pointer to the structure.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lint advises you to make `p_h_attr` a const pointer, but not a pointer to const. The placement of the `const` keyword matters. What is expected is:

```
static void get_dev_info_service_id_attr(ble_attribute_t * const p_h_attr)
    ...
```

But as others noted in comments, declaring a parameter const for a C function is at least contreversial: there is no gain because it is passed by value. Of course pointers to const is a quite different thing.

Comment: Nice. Better than my answer and even a couple of dozen seconds earlier (though this is not a race).

Comment: That is still a broken advise from lint. There's not much gain (if at all), and much visual noise, in making parameters const. That would be the same as saying `double sqrt(double n)` could be `double sqrt(const double n)`.

Comment: Whereas I agree with this interpretation of Lint's output, the particular advice it is giving is somewhat controversial.  I, for one, am not among those who put much stock in declaring function parameters `const` (with pointers to `const` data being a completely different question).

Comment: @CacahueteFrito I don't see the point of this at all, but I'm working to rules set by someone else and I am not in a position to argue about it.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito (and JohnBollinger): you are right. I was just explaining what Lint asked for, but did not want to support it. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @DiBosco IMHO, you should tell Lint to shut up in this specific case, as @89f3a1c says in his answer. Making the pointer `const` (not the pointee) is completely useless, and error-prone, as someone seeing `const` may think that the pointee (the struct) is unchanged in the function.  Silencing lint noise (or compiler warnings noise) by writing low quality code should not be an option.

Answer (score 3):

I think it means the following

```
static void get_dev_info_service_id_attr(ble_attribute_t * const p_h_attr)
{
    p_h_attr->p_attr = (void *)ble_char_system_id_value;
    p_h_attr->attr_len = sizeof(ble_char_system_id_value);
}
```

That is the pointer itself that should be constant not the pointed data. Though there is no great sense to use the qualifier const for the pointer because it is passed by value. That is the parameter is a local variable of the function

Comment: Cheers, Vlad. Your answer was right, but I accepted Serge's because he gave an explanation of the subtle difference.

Answer (score 1):

Most linters have the option to add exceptions to particular lines where the linters complains but it isn't right to do so. You should check you linter's documentation to find out how to prevent that from taking it as an error.

Usually, such exceptions take the form of specially formatted comments, which instruct the linter to skip the next line, or a certain code block, or a specific linter warning/error in all files (this may not go in a comment but directly to some config file where the linter has the rules saved).

EDIT

I realize, reading more carefully, that the other answers answer your question better. Hope this helps you in the future, though!

Comment: I realized the same, deleted my answer and upvoted the most convincing other one. Hint, hint.